# How to check whether user is admin after click"continue as"

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook quiz, but i had stuck with the following problem a couple of days. When user starts the game and after click "continue as" (the screen where facebook asks to get a couple of users information) i want to check whether that user who enters in the game is admin or not. So far, when user allow to share his informations, he enters in the game as user. I've tried a couple of different solutions, i have tried with sending a couple of different api's, i have read a tons of examples but so far i don't have any luck. At developers.facebook.com where my app is i have set the manage_pages and my user profile is select as a "administrator". This is my login.php script (the commented out  code are my checked solutions). Any help will be much appreciated.

```
    <?php 

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    include_once ('fb_sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '*******',
      'app_secret' => '*******',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

    try {
        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
        } else {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
     }
    if (isset($accessToken)) {

        if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

            // OAuth 2.0 client handler
            $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
            // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
            $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        }
        // validating the access token
        /*try {
            $request = $fb->get('/me');
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
                unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
                $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
                $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/facebookquiz/', $permissions);
                echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
                exit;
            }
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }*/
        // getting basic info about user
        try {
            $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name, last_name, email');
            $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='https://apps.facebook.com/facebookquiz/'</script>";
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        // priting basic info about user on the screen


        $first_name = $profile['first_name'];
        $last_name = $profile['last_name'];
        $email = $profile['email'];
        $fbUserId = $profile['id'];

        print_r ($profile);

        include_once('database/dbInsert.inc');
        include_once('database/db_select.inc');

        $fbUser = getUserByFBID($fbUserId);

        if($fbUser == false){
            $userID = insertUserInfo($fbUserId,$first_name, $last_name, $email);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userID;
        }else{
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $fbUser->Id;
        }


        header("Location: index.php");

        //redirect if is administrator
    } else {
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'publish_actions', 'manage_pages']; // optionnal 'user_managed_groups'
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/facebookquiz/login.php', $permissions);
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
    }
    ?><?php 

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

include_once ('fb_sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app-if',
  'app_secret' => 'app-secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }
if (isset($accessToken)) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }
    // validating the access token
    /*try {
        $request = $fb->get('/me');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/facebookquiz/', $permissions);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
            exit;
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }*/
    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name, last_name, email');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='https://apps.facebook.com/facebookquiz/'</script>";
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    // priting basic info about user on the screen


    $first_name = $profile['first_name'];
    $last_name = $profile['last_name'];
    $email = $profile['email'];
    $fbUserId = $profile['id'];

    print_r ($profile);

    include_once('database/dbInsert.inc');
    include_once('database/db_select.inc');

    $fbUser = getUserByFBID($fbUserId);

    if($fbUser == false){
        $userID = insertUserInfo($fbUserId,$first_name, $last_name, $email);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userID;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $fbUser->Id;
    }

    /*$getPages = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/me/accounts'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    $pageID = $getPages['data'][0]->id;
    $pageAccessToken = $getPages['data'][0]->accessToken;

    (new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'POST',
    '/' . $pageID . '/feed',
    array(
        'accessToken' => $pageAccessToken;
        'message' => 'Facebook app';
        )

    ))->execute();*/


    //foreach ($getPages['data'] as $key) {

        //print_r($getPages);

        /*echo $key->id;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $key->name;
        echo "<br>";*/

    //}

    /*$response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();*/
/*$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $_SESSION,
  'POST',
  '/883093058488924/roles',
  array (
    'user' => '123456789',
    'role' => 'administrators',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

var_dump($graphObject);*/


    header("Location: index.php");

    //redirect if is administrator

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'publish_actions', 'manage_pages']; // optionnal 'user_managed_groups'
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/facebookquiz/login.php', $permissions);
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Admin of what? The app? A certain page? …?

Comment: Admin of the app. The idea is, user can see only a question and can answer the question, while admin only can create a game.

Comment: Then you have to go via the application object and its roles edge, and see if the user is in that list. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/app/roles

Comment: Yes, i'm trying that, but i'm getting an error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookApp, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\FBQuiz\test.php on line 56 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\FBQuiz\fb_sdk\src\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 97

Comment: You are passing a string value where an object of a specific class is expected ...

Comment: $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
  "EAAMjKyAOClwBAAUaOd0pqwrOrjROfFcOEZCOgsxOZB4ZApQ6TyV0D5KsXUZCTVqnjj9KhaZCXlhDEpuAnZCmKmXv2CHetG8NNfCfvNSkCemR14Q4ZC5FXbAZBOQQ0uK9WISBgLH0XrXmKFlCMIzoTEx4GpKQXJqhiwYZD",
  'GET',
  '/883093058488924/roles'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();     //That long string is a facebook_access_token

Comment: The constructor Facebook\FacebookRequest does not _want_ a string.

Comment: What shoul i have to put there instead of a string? What object?

Comment: _“must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookApp”_